# InfoPath 2010 Switching views from Display to Edit form doesn't work!

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, form, display-form

I changed the edit, display and new form via InfoPath. It all seemed to work but I have one problem now.

I want a button on the Display from which has the name 'Update item', that switches the view to the edit form.

I created a picture button, and switching to the edit from does work.
But I have a Close button with the related rule (picture button too) and nothing happens when I click on it. Any ideas why?

But the more important problem I face: when I am on the edit form (which seems to work fine if I go to the form directly (over 'edit item')) some columns of the form appears in 'view only'-mode.

Can I change that?

Here is a similar question, but it seems to me like my problem is a bit different.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d082df64-875d-4b61-bb25-ad7621c5d6eb/infopath-2010-switching-views-from-display-to-edit-item-is-not-working?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious

Thanks!!

Comment: I ended up deleting the buttons from the display form and putting the 'Edit item' column after the ID in 'Modify this View'.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: This solution seemed to work in the first place, but sending data to the server gives out an error!**

I found that the solution provided in the link above doesnt solve my problem, but one of the answers provided as well helped me.

> Open SharePoint Designer
>
> • Navigate to the list which you’ve customized it to InfoPath
>
> • Under the Forms section >> Edit the page “displayifs.aspx”.
>
> • Find the option called “ListFormMode” then give it value “Editable” instated >of “ReadOnly“ to be like following :
>
> ```
>       ListFormMode="Editable".
> ```